# Ошибки в классе PDO

Tags: классы, pdo

Реализация по коду http://phpfaq.ru/pdo/pdo_wrapper#code
Возникает ошибка:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in

Если убрать run($sql, $args) тут:

```
run($sql, $args = [])
```

то возникает другая ошибка:

> Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'PDO' does not have a method 'select' in

Подскажите как от них избавиться. Сперва ошибка о том, что ожидается один параметр, а когда убираю $args, то пишет наоборот, что ожидается два параметра.
Сказка!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Надо подновить версию PHP.

Короткий синтаксис для определения массивов, `[]` существует в языке уже больше  5 лет, и даже версия РНР (5.4), в которой он появился, уже не поддерживается.

Но в качестве обходного варианта можно использовать классический синтаксис, `array()`

Comment: Спасибо помогло. Учусь только)
А вторую ошибку сам нашёл как исправить, просто плохо прочитал сообщение)

Comment: Я бы настоятельно не рекомендовал делать функцию select().  пользы от нее никакой, а вреда много. Если хочется сделать легкую манипуляцию данными, то это задача для для совсем другого класса. Но и в нем функции select не должно быть, а должны быть функция find(). В принципе, CRUD от предыдущего враппера подойдет.

Comment: Сперва я к Вашим ответам не прислушивался, но теперь понимаю, что Вы профи и спасибо Вам за помощь во всех моих вопросах.

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, будет не сильно глупо если я назову метод PDO_insert, который будет заносить значения в базу? Просто мне нужно что бы была структура в моей cms и что бы использовали мой класс с моими функциями и что бы не было бардака.

Comment: Для insert в принципе функция оправдана. Там тоже есть подводные камни, но меньше, чем с селектом. Вполне можно добавить в класс еще один метод, назвать его просто insert и передавать в него имя таблицы и массив с данными.